# How Scrape a Website with a user login popup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website with a user login popup. I can view the first page without logging in any information but if I want to scrape all the pages, I need to log in with my user name and password. I wrote some codes to try to solve it but it doesn't work.

Here is my code.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post('https://securities.stanford.edu/filings.html', data = {
        'dbconnect': 'y',
        'entryPoint': 1001,
        'numblogon': 0,
        'password': 'psword',
        'username': 'email',
    },verify = False)
```

I try to use this code to solve it but somehow it didn't work.

Here is the code that I used to scrape.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Filing Name', 'Filing Date', 'District Court', 
                           'Exchange', 'Ticker', 'Case_Url'])

for i in range(1,6):
    page = s.get(base_url + "filings.html?page=" + str(i), verify = False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    Records = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"table-link"})
    
    #Initializing all variables to be extracted
    for record in Records:

        #Initializing list for current record to be appended to dataframe
        addRecord = []

        #Fetching all children(td) elements of every table row
        children = record.findChildren("td" , recursive=True)

        #Extracting text of each td element and appending to new record list (in order)
        for child in children:
            addRecord.append(child.text.strip())

        #Extracting URL of case, prefixing base url and appending to new record list
        addRecord.append(base_url + record['onclick'].split("'")[1])

        #Appending current record to dataframe
        df.loc[len(df)] = addRecord
```

I tried the first 6 pages to test my code but the return dataframe that I got is only looping the first-page result.

I am wondering how can I solve the popup user login.

Thank you!

Comment: @chitown88 Thank you so much for helping me. I just sent you an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you were not posting the login info to the correct url.

Try this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import re

s = requests.Session()
payload = {
    'email': 'user@email.com',
    'pass': '1234Password',
    'remember': '0',
    'referer': 'index'}

url = 'https://securities.stanford.edu/login.json'
s.post(url, data = payload, verify = False)

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
page = 0
at_end = False
rows = []
while at_end == False:
    page += 1
    print('Page: %s' %page)
    url = 'https://securities.stanford.edu/filings.html?page={page}'.format(page=page)
    
    response = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    tb = soup.find('table') 
    df = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
    
    trs = tb.find_all('tr')
    for tr in trs:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
    
    links = tb.find_all('tr',{'class':'table-link'})
    hrefs = []
    for link in links:
        link_match = re.compile("\'(.*)\'")
        linkStr = 'https://securities.stanford.edu/' + link_match.search(link['onclick'])[1]
        hrefs.append(linkStr)
        
    
    df['Case_Url'] = hrefs
    final_df = final_df.append(df, sort=False)
    
    if final_df.duplicated().sum() > 0:
        final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
        at_end = True
```

**Output:**

```
print(final_df)
                                            Filing Name  ... Ticker
0                             Apex Clearing Corporation  ...    AMC
1                                         Volkswagen AG  ...  VWAGY
2                             Peloton Interactive, Inc.  ...   PTON
3                                       Pinterest, Inc.  ...   PINS
4                                 Boingo Wireless, Inc.  ...   WIFI
                                                ...  ...    ...
5989                                     Cephalon, Inc.  ...   CEPH
5990                             Silicon Graphics, Inc.  ...    SGI
5991  Donaldson, Lufkin & Jenrette Securities Corpor...  ...    NaN
5992                    Touchstone Software Corporation  ...   TSSW
5993                               ABS Industries, Inc.  ...   ABSI

[5994 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am wondering how did you figure out the correct URL ```'https://securities.stanford.edu/login.json'```

Comment: By looking at the Dev Tools, I was able to locate where the post request was sent. however it was little more trickier than that as sometimes the site will relaod too quickly before seeing the request. So I used the Chrome extension called "Tamper", which allows you to "pause" requests as they are made by the site. Using that, I could find when the username/password would be sent.

Comment: No wonder I couldnt find the correct URL. I was trying to use Dev Tools as well. Thank you so much for your help!